# Coordinates not accurate when converting to int

Tags: java, android, google-maps, coordinates

I'm getting coordinates from Facebook to places and these sometimes have up to 12 decimals. When converting these to int (* 1E6) I'm loosing accuracy since it's shaving off some digits.

For example, the double 59.313732591172 is represented as int 59313732.

How can I keep the accuracy? Is there any way to do this on Android? Using the [GeoPoint](http://code.google.com/intl/sv/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/GeoPoint.html) class I seem to be stuck with int.

Mike

Comment: Hi Mike it seems strange that you want to convert your location to int... Double will be more accurate than int. Can you explain why it is that you need it as an int?

Comment: despite the fact that 12 decimals is extremely precise... I didn't do the math, but I guess that 1E6 should be precise to a meter or two... Sure that this is necessary?

Comment: @travega: The Google Maps API I'm using has a class called GeoPoint which is used to pinpoint a location: http://code.google.com/intl/sv/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/GeoPoint.html And it only takes int as arguments. Every discussion on the net talks about converting double to int using * 1E6 but I'm experiencing some problems with that.

Comment: @WarrenFaith: The accuracy is anywhere from perfect (=when no shaving is done) to quite off (=most likely when both coordinates are shaved). Haven't done any math to what it exactly means. *BUT...* it just hit me that you might be correct. Those last digits are close enough and the results I'm seeing is more due to bad testdata. I'll check that out and post my findings here.

Comment: @WarrenFaith: Yeah, seems to be bad data. Thanks for the heads-up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `int` will only hold whole numbers, so you're seeing the behaviour you ask for.

```
59.313732591172 * 1E6 = 59313732.591172

(int)59313732.591172 = 59313732
```

If you need to keep more digits, either keep using double, convert to a `long` instead of an `int` and multiply by a bigger number (e.g. 1E12)

This is just how casting floating-point to int/long works in any typed language. Here, it's a Java feature, and nothing specific to Android.

Comment: I know. The problem is that the API I'm using (the GeoPoint class: http://code.google.com/intl/sv/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/GeoPoint.html) only takes int as args.

Comment: Ah. Bad Google. Adding 0.5 before casting to int is probably the best you can do (to get round up/down right). As a side note, when I've used Facebook events, I've found looking up street address seems more accurate than using GPS references. Maybe they spike data to deter data theft (some in-car GPS systems have tainted maps for this reason). However, a rough calculation suggests a microdegree is accurate to about 10cm (Circumfence in km * 1000 / (360x1e6)), so I'd listen to Warren. It'd be good to edit the question to focus on GeoPoint to avoid repeating yourself in comments.

Answer (score 0):

`int` is too short for some numbers (actually, for most of the numbers) since it has only 32-bits. Use `long` instead. See [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)